# What type should <svg> elements be?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am unable to figure what type `SVG` element should be so that it is rendered in my component, and also I want to make it editable.

```
export interface Formulas {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  formula: string;
  image: 
}

export const formula: Formulas[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "circle",
    formula: `$$ C = 2 \\pi r $$`,
    image: (<svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line y1="79.5" x2="160" y2="79.5" stroke="#3A3D40"/>
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="79.5" stroke="#696C71"/>
    <line x1="79.562" y1="79.7588" x2="117.562" y2="10.7588" stroke="#3A3D40"/>
    <rect x="89" y="35" width="20" height="20" fill="#202124"/>
    <path d="M100.451 42.564C100.291 42.564 100.123 42.612 99.9471 42.708C99.7711 42.796 99.5831 42.96 99.3831 43.2C99.1911 43.44 98.9831 43.792 98.7591 44.256L98.0991 48H97.3791L98.2431 43.104C98.2911 42.824 98.3071 42.66 98.2911 42.612C98.2751 42.556 98.2071 42.524 98.0871 42.516L97.4271 42.456L97.4871 42.156H99.1311L98.9031 43.44C99.2311 42.912 99.5591 42.548 99.8871 42.348C100.215 42.14 100.523 42.036 100.811 42.036C101.059 42.036 101.279 42.104 101.471 42.24C101.671 42.376 101.815 42.576 101.903 42.84L101.291 43.38C101.211 43.084 101.103 42.876 100.967 42.756C100.839 42.628 100.667 42.564 100.451 42.564Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
    <rect x="69" y="88" width="20" height="20" fill="#202124"/>
    <path d="M80.8838 101.06C80.6118 101.06 80.3998 100.968 80.2478 100.784C80.0958 100.6 80.0238 100.308 80.0318 99.908C79.7358 100.348 79.4238 100.66 79.0958 100.844C78.7758 101.028 78.4438 101.12 78.0998 101.12C77.6358 101.12 77.2518 100.976 76.9478 100.688C76.6518 100.4 76.4518 100.016 76.3478 99.536C76.2438 99.048 76.2438 98.512 76.3478 97.928L76.3958 97.664C76.4918 97.128 76.6758 96.664 76.9478 96.272C77.2198 95.88 77.5438 95.576 77.9198 95.36C78.3038 95.144 78.7118 95.036 79.1438 95.036C79.4958 95.036 79.7998 95.104 80.0558 95.24C80.3118 95.376 80.5278 95.568 80.7038 95.816L81.1838 93.068C81.2318 92.788 81.2478 92.624 81.2318 92.576C81.2158 92.52 81.1478 92.488 81.0278 92.48L80.3798 92.42L80.4278 92.12H82.0718L80.8238 99.2C80.7518 99.608 80.7118 99.92 80.7038 100.136C80.7038 100.352 80.7278 100.504 80.7758 100.592C80.8238 100.672 80.8918 100.712 80.9798 100.712C81.0998 100.712 81.2318 100.636 81.3758 100.484C81.5278 100.332 81.6598 100.084 81.7718 99.74L82.1678 100.004C81.9918 100.364 81.7918 100.632 81.5678 100.808C81.3438 100.976 81.1158 101.06 80.8838 101.06ZM77.0918 98.288C76.9638 99.04 76.9998 99.64 77.1998 100.088C77.4078 100.536 77.7278 100.76 78.1598 100.76C78.3518 100.76 78.5518 100.716 78.7598 100.628C78.9758 100.532 79.1958 100.364 79.4198 100.124C79.6518 99.884 79.8878 99.544 80.1278 99.104L80.5958 96.404C80.4438 96.06 80.2518 95.808 80.0198 95.648C79.7958 95.48 79.5078 95.396 79.1558 95.396C78.6278 95.396 78.1998 95.588 77.8718 95.972C77.5438 96.356 77.3238 96.888 77.2118 97.568L77.0918 98.288Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
    <circle cx="79.5" cy="79.5" r="2.5" fill="#696C71"/>
    </svg>),
  },
];
```

Comment: Do you need to be more specific than "element"?

Comment: Rendered JSX is always just `React.JSX.Element`, regardless of what tag was rendered. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgWwOYwLwwDwQG4oPQB8AUHnjOTAHoD8QA

Comment: @jonrsharpe, if it renders `svg` correctly then I do not want to be more specific than "element"

Comment: @AlexWayne When setting the image type as `React.JSX.Elemet`, I am getting the error as `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'`

Comment: Image can be: `image: string; ` and you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property in React to render in html. Obviously named that for a reason. `<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formula[0].image }}
/>`

Comment: Are you sure the code in your question is the same code generating that error? Because this works fine: https://tsplay.dev/Wyjqxw

Comment: @AlexWayne Yeah it is the same code, and I can see that it is working there, but I am unable to understand as to why I am getting errors in vscode with the same code.

Comment: I figured out the error, apparently I was getting the error when my file name was `formula.ts`, changing it to `formula.tsx` fixed it. Thanks for the help tho.